# error C2248: 'klientPracownik::klientPracownik' : cannot access private member declared in class 'klientPracownik'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have error in line:

```
klientPracownik obiekt4(4, "prezes", 99);
```

"4" is underlined and cause error:

error C2248: 'klientPracownik::klientPracownik' : cannot access private member declared in class 'klientPracownik'
I have no idea why, cause everythink is public.
Please, help me.
Here is code, i deleted everythink what is unimportant:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class osoba{
public:
    int id;
    osoba(){}
    osoba(int ide) :id(ide) {}
    virtual ~osoba();
};

class klient : virtual public osoba{
public:
    float rabat;
    klient::klient(float rab);
};

klient::klient(float rab) : rabat(rab){}


class pracownik : virtual public osoba{
public:
    char* stanowisko;
    pracownik::pracownik(char* stan);
};

pracownik::pracownik(char * stan) : stanowisko(stan){}

class klientPracownik :public pracownik, public klient {
    klientPracownik(int ide, char* stan, float rabat);
    ~klientPracownik();
};

klientPracownik::klientPracownik(int ide, char* stan, float rabat) :osoba(ide), pracownik(stan), klient(rabat) {}
klientPracownik::~klientPracownik(){}

int main(){

    klientPracownik obiekt4(4, "prezes", 99);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `klientPracownik` class is missing `public:` -- which means all its members / methods are private (even its constructor).

Comment: Oh no, it was so easy... I am so dumb. I was looking for this about an hour. Thanks a lot :)